# Where to find project Id to Google Analytics Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

My customer company has given me access to their *Google Analytics* premium account and I can log in to see their information. They have also prepared a number of queries on Big Query and I need to download their result into the company's database (most probably via their .NET library).

When I try to test the funtions via the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/bigquery/v2/), it asks for a  `projectId`. Where can I find the project Id? When I log in to the [Big Query account](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/) of the company, I see no projects created there. So how can they have prepared the queries they want without a project?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery API needs to be enabled for the company's account. You may try doing this yourself if you have access or ask them to do so.

They can add your email address as a member to the project.

Comment: actually I think the companies data has to be exported to Google Analytics they need to contact there Google Analytics premium manager.

Answer (score -5):

You can find your project id here https://console.developers.google.com/